# ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add login with omniauth Google, facebook and twitter in my Rails app
I follow omniauth tutorials from official docs on github. But there are not available resources for
API only app, and I'm beginner and couldn't found useful resources for backend only. Please help me to accomplish this task.
I'll provide my code and guide me in the right way.
Here my server logs when i hit API request from postman at http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback  and some time getting

Started POST "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2023-09-12 18:49:21 +0530
D, [2023-09-12T18:49:21.941614 #38273] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
E, [2023-09-12T18:49:21.943750 #38273] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as */*

and some time getting

Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback" for ::1 at 2023-09-12 19:08:53 +0530
D, [2023-09-12T19:08:53.125607 #39856] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2023-09-12T19:08:53.128328 #39856] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! undefined method `expired?' for nil:NilClass: NoMethodError, undefined method` expired?' for nil:NilClass
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as */*

**controller**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def handle_omniauth(provider)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    
    if @user.persisted?
      render json: { status: 'success', message: "Successfully authenticated via #{provider.capitalize}", user: @user }
    else
      render json: { status: 'error', message: 'Authentication failed', errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  
  def google_oauth2
    handle_omniauth('Google')
  end

  def twitter
    handle_omniauth('Twitter')
  end

  def facebook
    handle_omniauth('Facebook')
  end
end
```

**model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Devise modules
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :twitter, :facebook]

  # OmniAuth callback method to create or find a user
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)

    if user
      user.update(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    else
      user = User.create(
        provider: auth.provider,
        uid: auth.uid,
        email: auth.info.email,
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      )
    end

    user
  end
end
```

I've setup credentials in devise.rb  and credentials.yml
i try to debug but control not reach at debugger.

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
```

routes are well defined,
but still i'm not able login with omniauth.

```
**gems are **
# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'
```

I want to add third party login but getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

The Rails docs say that `protect_from_forgery` adds this line:

```
    before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
```

which is in conflict with your other line

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

An authenticity token doesn't make sense in this context, since you are expecting a callback from a third-party, not a form you have generated yourself.

You should remove the line `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`
and see what happens